# How to use generator output and list in one cycle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

```
my_list = [1,2,3]

def my_gen():
    yield 4
    yield 5
    yield 6

for i in my_list:
  print(i) # 1,2,3

for i in my_gen():
  print(i) # 4,5,6
```

How to implement the next cycle? I expect to get: `1,2,3,4,5,6`

```
for i in [my_list, my_gen()]:
  print(i) # 1, 2, 3 <generator object my_gen...> -> 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: not sure what it is you are trying to do but it looks like `zip` could be useful

Comment: @Ma0 zip combines 2 iterators: (1,4), (2,5), (3,5). I need [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a helper for this purpose: [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
for i in itertools.chain(my_list, my_gen()):
    print(i)
```

---

Note: there is also a similar function for aggregating access to maps (dicts, ...) [ChainMap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap)

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is the same output, you can convert the generator to a list.

This will not be enough though, because you'll print the list itself, not the values inside.

What you need is to unpack the lists, and use that in the for loop.

```
my_list = [1,2,3]

def my_gen():
    yield 4
    yield 5
    yield 6

for i in [*my_list, *list(my_gen())]:
  print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in zip(my_list, my_gen()):
  print(*i)
```

To be honest, I didn't really understand your question. please explain yourself better.

Edit: the `*` is to unpack the tuple that the `zip()` function created.

Answer (score 0):

A quite unknown functionality is the syntax `yield from`, which allows to delegate to another generator the element to yield. This has the advantage of not converting `my_gen` to a list. For instance:

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3]

def my_gen():
    yield 4
    yield 5
    yield 6

def my_final_gen():
    yield from my_list
    yield from my_gen()

for x in my_final_gen():
    print(x)
```